# Edgy fonts using font face

Tags: css, font-face

I am trying to use the CSS font face property. I've made it chance the font to the right one, however it looks very edgy on the Windows platform. Especially Chrome looks awful.

When using OSX all browsers are just perfect.

How can I avoid these awful looking fonts?

On OSX Chrome:

[image]

On Windows Chrome:

[image]

Comment: I 'think' that it's not a windows/mac issue, but more likely that one of your fonts isn't converted well. You use `woff` then `ttf` then `svg`. I reckon that on your mac it presents you with one of them, and on your windows machine it presents you with another. Possibly the windows machine uses `ttf` in all cases and just your `ttf` file isn't converted using anti-aliasing, where on your mac it presents you with the `woff` in all cases and that file is correct. What if you force just `woff` or `ttf` on both machines, is the difference still there?

Comment: On Windows using IE it looks fine, most likely because it uses the `eot`, this is in line with my earlier comment stating that probably one of your font files is not using anti-alias.

Comment: @Bazzz the fonts are ok, IE9+ also uses WOFF and not EOT. Chrome does crappy rendering in some cases.

Comment: @Bazzz I could imagine that is the problem. The original font is *ttf*, and I just converted them using http://www.font2web.com/. Does anyone know a tool I can use to convert my *ttf* font to the remaining formats, and be sure the quality is good?

Comment: @Carvelis I didn't know about IE9+ using `woff` but I also used IE9 in IE8 mode and in IE7 mode and they most likely use the `eot` and are fine as well. I'm pretty sure either the `ttf` or the `svg` results in crap rendering in some browers and the problem lies with the font file. I'm inclined to say the `ttf`.

Answer (score 0):

The Segoe font is already installed on most Windows PC's. This can cause problems when you are also trying to link it with CSS. Try renaming the font in your CSS so that it has a different name than the built-in Windows font.

Also, Chrome just doesn't render TTF/WOFF fonts very well. You can get around that by prioritizing the SVG font (by putting it higher up in the font list). This will make Chrome select the SVG font (but most other browsers will still use the WOFF font). [See here](http://www.vandersterren.com/blog/2012/04/font-embedding-chrome-and-anti-aliasing/) for more information.